# Problem with toc and chapter commands using Greek letters

Tags: table-of-contents, greek

I am having a problem trying to use xgreek with chapters name and toc. For some weird reason, before formatting my pc, everything was working fine. But now, when i try to compile my report i get gibberish instead of the word "Κεφάλαιο" which is the Greek word for chapter. Same thing with "Περιεχόμενα" and contents. I can't seem to find what am i doing wrong. Could very well be a wrong preference in TexStudio also. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xunicode}
%better usage of footers and headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{+0}%
    \newpage}



\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage[procnames]{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim} %comment package
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = blue,
urlcolor  = blue,
citecolor = blue,
anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}
\newcommand{\mylength}{\hrule{10pt}}


\graphicspath{ {./Recources/} }

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filcenter}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}





\usepackage{tocloft}
%\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\fontsize{22}{15}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\HRule\vskip+1em \hfil \huge\MakeUppercase }
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\par\noindent\HRule\par\vskip-3.3em}


\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{8.3em}


\begin{document}
    \definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
    \definecolor{comments}{RGB}{0,0,113}
    \definecolor{red}{RGB}{160,0,0}
    \definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,150,0}   
    \thispagestyle{empty}


    \chapter*{ΠΕΡΙΛΗΨΗ}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ΠΕΡΙΛΗΨΗ}

    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}

    \chapter*{ΕΥΧΑΡΙΣΤΙΕΣ}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ΕΥΧΑΡΙΣΤΙΕΣ}



    \clearpage



    \setcounter{page}{9}
    {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \clearpage



    \chapter{ΕΙΣΑΓΩΓΗ}
\end{document}
```

And here are some screenshots of the gibberish results: 
[image]

[image]

Lastly, i have to mention that if i comment out the use of xgreek package, everything works fine, but in english. Also i really want the xgreek instead of other greek language packages, because it has a great support of greek hyphenation.

Comment: I can't test with `CMU serif` but after commenting out, I've got nice headings.

Comment: This is what I get from your example: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tde0R.png) My impression is that your version of `xgreek.sty` has been saved in an encoding different from UTF-8.

Comment: I got the basically the picture egreg linked-to, even using a different `.ttf` font

Comment: Finally, after installing CMU serif correctly, there are no weird characters. Most likely egreg's assumption about the encoding ist true

Comment: Hey fellas. How can i test what @egreg said about encoding? And also, if that's whats wrong, can i change it manually? Thanks again, and sorry for my big delay, my internet is down most of the time today :/

Comment: @M.Achilles If you're working on Linux (and/or MacOS), you could try `file foo.tex` -- it should report `utf-8` encoding` if the file is encoded that way

Comment: I tested with notepad++ (since i am using win 10) and its encoding is UTF-8 :/. Any other idea of what can be wrong? Or maybe i didn't configure something right at texstudio for example? Damn, i am so lost :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some testing, and lots of internet connection problems, i found out what's wrong. I had MikTex 2.9.5721 installed and it seems that this version has a bug or incompatibility with windows 10. After i installed Tex Live everything worked like a charm. I am posting this answer, so others with MikTex may know. Thanks for all the help and your time guys. Cheers!